# Laravel Factory: указание значения поля для Primary Key (типа VARCHAR)

Tags: php, laravel

Есть таблица, в которой поле для **Primary Key** типа `VARCHAR`. Использую `factory` для заполнения таблицы записями. Все работает хорошо, за исключением установки сгенерированного **Primary Key**. Конфликтов значений поля для **Primary Key** нету.

Значение для **Primary Key** генерирую таким образом: `$faker->unique()->regexify('[a-zA-Z0-9]{60}')`.

Моё определение фабрики для модели:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Auth\ConfirmationEmail::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'token' => $faker->unique()->regexify('[a-zA-Z0-9]{60}'),
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'counts' => $faker->randomDigit,
        'status' => $faker->randomElement(config('auth.confirm.status')),
    ];
});
```

Как я понял `factory` намерянно не задаёт значение поля для **Primary Key**. Как это можно обойти без костылей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно отключить инкремент для **Primary Key** в моделе.

Добавив в модель строки:

```
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
```

Решение нашел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604605/laravel-eloquent-after-save-id-becomes-0